# How to send email from bash via a gmail account?

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, email, gmail

I have a bash script which periodically check whether or not a certain ruby script is up. The ruby script has to be up 24/7. If it's not, the bash script has to send email.

That's my vision of how to ensure the ruby is always up. So what's the easiest way to send email from bash via gmail?

Or is there a better way to notify the admin that something is wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to send it via gmail? If you just want to send an email, you can use `mail` command.

Comment: @t_thirupathi, gmail I guess

Comment: @mauro, what's that?

Comment: It's the Message Transfer Agent: that piece of software that moves emails from one computer to another. The command line tool you use to "compose" your email (for example mail) is not important. Ok, let's do this way, will answer with my working solution. You might need to change it a little if you have a different MTA.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I have on one of my Raspberry PIs. It sends emails using my gmail account. I do use "SSMTP" as MTA and "mailx" as command line tool to compose the emails. mailx is activated via cron.

Configuration is very simple. These are the relevant part of my SSMTP config in `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.cnf`:

```
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
root=xyz@gmail.com
# The place where the mail goes
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
# The full hostname (FQDN of the Linux box used to send emails)
hostname=planck.xyz.it
# Gmail account username & passed:
AuthUser=xyz@gmail.com
AuthPass=xyz
# Other config params:
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
FromLineOverride=YES
```

I have SSMTP automatically started at boot.

Then, you can send emails from the command line. I do receive stats from my Raspberry Pi every night. This is my crontab entry:

```
00 03 * * * /usr/local/bin/xyz.sh | mailx -s "xyz xyz at $(date)" xyz.xyz@xyz.com
```

You can - of course - send email (via mailx) to any valid email address

Answer (score 0):

> So what's the easiest way to send email from bash via gmail?

I redirect `/dev/null` to `mutt` to make it work without a UI to send E-mails CLI.

I keep the following function in my *.bashrc*:

```
# Usage: em <list-of-contacts> <mutt-options>
em () { 
    local contacts=()
    while [[ -n $1 && $1 != -* ]]; do
        contacts+=("$1")
        shift
    done
    mutt "$@" -- "${contacts[@]}" < /dev/null
}
```

In *.mutt-alias* I keep a list of contacts and their E-mails, which allows me to conveniently send E-mails by executing something like this:

`em daniel david -s 'Hello Daniel and David' -a /home/rany/Books/K_and_R.pdf`

Which will send an email to Daniel and David, with the subject *Hello Daniel and David* and the attachment */home/rany/Books/K_and_R.pdf*.

I sometimes want to write a very short E-mail body, so I execute the following Bash command:

`em daniel david -s 'Hi guys' -i <(printf '%s\n' "Check out this too!")`

Which might be helpful to you in composing and sending a short notification for your admin.

---

If you happen to run Archlinux like I do, see [Mutt Installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mutt#Installing) on how to setup Mutt with IMAP, POP3, Maildir and SMTP configuration.